# How to make this function run more than once JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need this code to run more than once. It runs only when I click the button to append the images, and click the button to remove them. The third click doesn't append the images again

```
<button class="" onclick="showImages(this,'100000,jpg','1111111.jpg','5');"></button>
<div id="5" class="">
... //when I run the function it appends the <img> tag here
</div>

function showImages(button, image1, image2, id) { //user clicks a button "show"
    if (image2 == "") { //if there is only one image
        $('#show' + id + '').append('<img class=\"one\" src=\"images/' + image1 + '\" />'); //creates a div with 1 image
        button.onclick = function () { //clicks it second time
            $('#show' + id + '').empty(); //removes the div with image
        };
    } else { //if there are 2 images
        $('#show' + id + '').append('<img class=\"two\" src=\"images/' + image1 + '\" /><img src=\"images/' + image2 + '\" />'); //div with 2 images
        button.onclick = function () { //...
            $('#show' + id + '').empty(); //...
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: "How to make this function run, so to say, 24/7?" I cannot understand the question

Comment: @roasted me too. He even not put code with usage this code. Please provide more information.

Comment: there, I've changed it... is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you edited your post it is better way to give you another answer. By this `onclick="showImages(this,'100000,jpg','1111111.jpg','5');"` you attached one handler on button click. Later in this `button.onclick = function () { $('#show' + id + '').empty(); };` you gave one more handler.
Now you have two handlers: one of them show images and another one kills it immediately. This is why your code works only once (until second handler not binded).

Lets fix it. HTML:

```
<button id="my_button" image_1="10000.jpg" image_2="1111111.jpg" target_id="5"></button> <!-- move away javascript from HTML; put necessary data in button attributes -->
<div id="5">
...
</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
var toggleImages = function( event ){

  /* retrieve clicked button itself and all needed attributes */
  var button = $( event.target ),
      image_1 = "images/" + button.attr( 'image_1' ),
      image_2 = "images/" + button.attr( 'image_2' ),
      target = $( '#' + button.attr( 'target_id' ) );

  /* if no images shown – show it */
  if( 0 == target.find( 'img' ).length ){
    target.append( '<img src="' + image_1 + '" />' );
    if( 'undefined' != typeof image_2 ){
      target.append( '<img src="' + image_2 + '" />' );
    }
  /* if images was shown – remove it */
  } else {
    target.empty();
  }
}
$( '#my_button' ).on( 'click', toggleImages ); /* bind click handler only one time */
```